# ARJUNA012210: Unable to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to resolve address

Tags: jboss7.x, jta, jboss-eap-6

While starting my JBoss in domain mode (first instance), I am getting following WARN as part of `server.log` in the console....

I am curious to know what caused the issue...... does it needs to be rectified..... what are the implication if didn't go for any fix for this warning......

> [Server:server-two] 13:55:55,198 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Expired Entry Monitor) ARJUNA012210: Unable to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to resolve address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host entry is missing. Make entry in `hosts` file...

If your system is windows, `Start->Run->Drivers`
 ->and make the host entry in `etc/hosts` (need admin rights to edit `hosts` file)

If your system is UNIX based,
 ->open the file `$sudo vim /etc/hosts` and make the host entry.

In the present scenario host entry is for local system, to get the local system ip in UNIX run `$ifconfig` and in Windows run `>ipconfig` in command prompt.